# Reading a File into a 2D Array - Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException()

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Hi I've been doing Project Euler problems lately but I'm having trouble with Problem 18, here it is:

By starting at the top of the triangle below and moving to adjacent numbers on the row below, the maximum total from top to bottom is 23.

3

7 4

2 4 6

8 5 9 3

That is, 3 + 7 + 4 + 9 = 23.

Find the maximum total from top to bottom of the triangle below:

75

95 64

17 47 82

18 35 87 10

20 04 82 47 65

19 01 23 75 03 34

88 02 77 73 07 63 67

99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92

41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33

41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29

53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14

70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57

91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48

63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31

04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23

NOTE: As there are only 16384 routes, it is possible to solve this problem by trying every route. However, Problem 67, is the same challenge with a triangle containing one-hundred rows; it cannot be solved by brute force, and requires a clever method! ;o)

My algorithm for finding the max total is correct. I tested it by manually entering the numbers in a 2d array and the program ran fine. The reason I don't want to do it that way is as this Problem says Problem 67 is the same except much larger numbers and I don't want to be typing numbers all day and also I want to practice manipulating files etc.

Anyway to the point I suppose the best thing I can do really is show you my code and the errors I'm getting. I did some debugging and it seems to be how I'm converting the string of numbers into an array of digits. When I run the program it gives an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(). The .txt file consists of the large group of numbers in the problem description above.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Problem18 p18 = new Problem18() ;
    p18.maxTotalPath() ;
}

public int[][] readFile() throws Exception
{
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() ;
    InputStream file = loader.getResourceAsStream("Triangle.txt") ;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file) ;

    int[][] triangle = new int[15][15] ;
    int m = 0, n = 0 ;
    String line ;
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        line = scan.nextLine() ;
        String[] numbers = line.split(" ") ;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length ; i++)
        {
            triangle[m][n] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]) ;
            //System.out.print(triangle[m][n] + " ") ;
            n += 1 ;
        }
        n = 0 ;
        // System.out.println("") ;
        m += 1 ;
    }
    scan.close() ;
    return triangle ;
}

public void maxTotalPath() throws Exception
{
    int[][] arr = readFile() ;
    for (int i = arr.length - 2 ; i >= 0 ; i--) 
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < arr[i].length; j++) 
        {
            arr[i][j] += Math.max(arr[i + 1][j], arr[i + 1][j + 1]); 
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(arr[0][0])) ;
}
```

The errors then are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15
at com.jconnolly.projeuler.problems.Problem18.maxTotalPath(Problem18.java:83)
at com.jconnolly.projeuler.problems.Problem18.main(Problem18.java:44)
```

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: which is line Problem18.java:83?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your `readFile` function is working as it should.  Your `maxTotalPath` is trying to access the wrong memory in the inner loop.  If `j` goes all the way to `arr[i].length-1`, then when you access `arr[i+1][j+1]`, you will be reaching memory beyond the bounds of the array.

```
for (int j = 0 ; j < arr[i].length-1; j++) 
{
    arr[i][j] += Math.max(arr[i + 1][j], arr[i + 1][j + 1]); 
}
```

## Correcting the wrong answer

I think this is what you need to do

```
for (int j = 0 ; j < arr[i].length; j++) 
{
    if (j != arr[i].length-1) {
        arr[i][j] += Math.max(arr[i + 1][j], arr[i + 1][j + 1]); 
    } else {
        arr[i][j] += arr[i+1][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes rahulserver 83 seems to be the problem to which Logan and Kirk have now elaborated on and fixed. However when the program runs it doesn't provide me with the correct answer which I got when I ran the manually entered 2d array! Any suggestions to why that is? Thanks for the help so far

Comment: @user2646514 Since you don't go over the last row, I believe it doesn't take it into account maybe?  Have a look and let me know!

Comment: Spot on Kirk! Correct answer. Thanks for that much appreciated! Have been trying to figure it out for a while now. Thanks for the very quick responses also. Put the same question up on another forum and it didn't even have a view after 2 days never mind a response so thanks again.

Comment: Also I'd upvote only I'm new to the forum and can't upvote until I get 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

maxTotalPath the inner loop should go to arr[i].length - 1, which will at least stop the exception